# Column change does not trigger event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, ui-grid

I have an angular grid, and I want to save the order of the columns when the user moves them, and for that I have this:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventColumns', function (event, newColumns) {
            alert("do something");
        });
```

The problem is that the 'ngGridEventColumns' event is not triggered when I move the columns, and have no idea how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Grid-Events says the syntax is `$scope.$emit('ngGridEventColumns', newColumns);`

Comment: This code emits the event that will be handled by my code. The problem is that this code is not executed by ui-grid when I move the columns.